# Conditional string replacement

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, string-manipulation

I have a list of text and need to replace an element based on the text that appears in the element before it. Example of my list:

```
list={{"yes","can","fgh"},{"yes","can",""},{"yes","not","fgh"},{"yes","can","srts"},
      {"yes","not","h"}}
```

I would like to replace all items in column 3 with `"This"` when column 2's entry is `"can"`.

I have tried to do this using `/.` and If but without success. I think I need to use a rule but don't know the first thing about how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Replace[list, {x_, "can", _} :> {x, "can", "This"}, 1]
```

OR

```
list /. {x_, "can", _} :> {x, "can", "This"}
```

> ```
> {{"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "fgh"},
>  {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}}
> ```

As per your comment, use `Alternatives` (`|`):

```
Replace[list, {x_, y : "can" | "cann", _} :> {x, y, "This"}, 1]
```

Comment: Can you please walk me through what these symbols mean so I can use them in future? The first option you have given I read like this:

Comment: @LaraJordan Sure. What I've done here is use rules with pattern matching. With `Replace`, *Mathematica* tries to match the first argument using rules provided in the second argument. In this case the first argument is your original `list` which containes a list of triples. So I matched those triples with the rule `{x_, "can", _}`. What this rule says is match any triple where the second column is "can", then using `:>` (`RuleDelayed`), I then replace the matched triples with `{x, "can", "This"}`, where I keep the first two columns the same but replace the third column with the desired `"This"`

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/28073#28073) is a good resource, if you're not familiar with *Mathematica*

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much solves it but I have an addition to the question. What if instead of just replacing all items in column 3 with "This" when column 2's entry is "can", I also want to apply this rule when items in column 2 are any in a list {"can","cann",...}. I have tried using Table but this just gives me x sets of lists, each one with one rule applied.

Comment: @LaraJordan See my update.

Comment: So instead of writing "can" | "cann" ....how do I refer to the list {"can","cann",...} and not hard code the items? That is why I thought of using Table, something like Replace[list, {x_, y : {list}[[i]],_} :> {x, y, "This"}, 1]

Comment: @LaraJordan What do you mean by hardcode the list? you have to know this list beforehand, so you can save it as a variable e.g. `ss = Alternatives["can", "cann", ...]`, then use `ss` in the code above.

Comment: So I can say Replace[list, {x_, y : ss,_} :> {x, y, "This"}, 1] ? I thought I'd have to refer to an element of like Table[Replace[list, {x_, y : ss[[i]], _} :> {x, y, "This"}, 1],{i,1,10}] for example and that would leave me with something I didn't want. Could you elaborate as to how I'd use ss(the list of alternatives) in the example instead of writing out the whole list?

Comment: @LaraJordan Use `ss` like this: `Replace[list, {x_, y : ss, _} :> {x, y, "This"}, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{"yes", "can", "fgh"}, {"yes", "can", ""}, {"yes", "not", "fgh"}, 
        {"yes", "can", "srts"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}};
```

An alternative is to use `ReplacePart` as follows:

```
ReplacePart[#, Position[#, {x_, "can", _}] -> {"yes", "can", "This"}] &@list
```

> ```
> {{"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "fgh"},
>  {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}}
> ```

Or using `ReplaceList` with `SubsetMap`:

```
pos = ReplaceList[#, {___, s : {x_, "can", _}, ___} :> 
      {Splice @@ Position[#, s], Length@s}] &@list;

SubsetMap[Array["This" &, Length@pos] &, list, pos]
```

> ```
> {{"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "fgh"},
>  {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{"yes", "can", "fgh"}, {"yes", "can", ""}, {"yes", "not", "fgh"}, 
  {"yes", "can", "srts"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}};

 p = Position[list, "can"] /. {a_, _} :> {a, 3}

MapAt["This" &, p] @ list
```

{{"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not",
"fgh"}, {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}}

Also

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> "This", p] @ list
```

and

```
ReplacePart[p :> "This"] @ list
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{"yes", "can", "fgh"}, {"yes", "can", ""}, {"yes", "not", 
   "fgh"}, {"yes", "cann", "srts"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}}
```

---

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[list, {{a_, b : "can" | "cann", _}} :> {a, b, "This"}]
```

---

**Using  `SequenceCases`:** (for comparison with `SequenceReplace` only)

```
SequenceCases[list, {{a_, b_, c_}} :> 
  If[StringMatchQ[b, "can" | "cann"], {a, b, "This"}, {a, b, c}]]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "can", "This"}, {"yes", "not",
> "fgh"}, {"yes", "cann", "This"}, {"yes", "not", "h"}}